# How to get rows between time intervals

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have `delivery slots` that has a `from` column (`datetime`).

Delivery slots are stored as 1 hour to 1 hour and 30 minute intervals, daily.
i.e. 3.00am-4.30am, 6.00am-7.30am, 9.00am-10.30am and so forth

```
  id  |        from         
------+---------------------
    1 | 2016-01-01 03:00:00 
    2 | 2016-01-01 04:30:00 
    3 | 2016-01-01 06:00:00 
    4 | 2016-01-01 07:30:00 
    5 | 2016-01-01 09:00:00 
    6 | 2016-01-01 10:30:00 
    7 | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 
    8 | 2016-01-02 03:00:00 
    9 | 2016-01-02 04:30:00 
   10 | 2016-01-02 06:00:00 
   11 | 2016-01-02 07:30:00 
   12 | 2016-01-02 09:00:00 
   13 | 2016-01-02 10:30:00 
   14 | 2016-01-02 12:00:00
```

I’m trying to get all `delivery_slots` between the hours of 3.00am - 4.30 am. Ive got the following so far:

```
SELECT * FROM delivery_slots WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM delivery_slots.from) >= 3 AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM delivery_slots.from) >= 0 AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM delivery_slots.from) <= 4 AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM delivery_slots.from) <= 30;
```

Which *kinda* works. Kinda, because it is only returning delivery slots that have minutes of `00`.

Thats because of the last `where` condition (`EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM delivery_slots.from) <= 30`)

To give you an idea, of what I am trying to expect:

```
  id   |        from         
-------+---------------------
    1  | 2016-01-01 03:00:00 
    2  | 2016-01-01 04:30:00 
    8  | 2016-01-02 03:00:00 
    9  | 2016-01-02 04:30:00 
    15 | 2016-01-03 03:00:00 
    16 | 2016-01-03 04:30:00 
             etc...
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: `because it is only returning delivery slots that have minutes of 00` ... I just tested locally on Postgres using you data, and it returned the data you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (not tested)

```
SELECT * FROM delivery_slots WHERE delivery_slots.from::time >= '03:00:00' AND delivery_slots.from::time <= '04:30:00'
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, in my mind, is to cast the `from` column as a type [`time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html) and do a where `>=` and `<=`, like so

```
select * from testing where (date::time >= '3:00'::time and date::time <= '4:30'::time);
```